# process.env.CI = true build failed

Tags: reactjs

I have a project written in react-script and during build I got error

```
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.

resolve-url-loader: webpack misconfiguration
  webpack or the upstream loader did not supply a source-map
```

I tried to set up my build script like this     `"build": "CI=false && react-scripts build"`
but then I got an error `'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`
any suggestions what change I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable in the script command:

```
"build": "CI=false react-scripts build"
```

Comment: same error 'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable in the script command with cross-env:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

```
"build": "cross-env CI=false react-scripts build"
```